# Let $K/\mathbb Q$ be a number field and a Galois extension. Show $K$ contains the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d_K})$ where $d_K = \mathrm{disc}(K)$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb Q$ be a number field and a Galois extension. Show $K$ contains the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d_K})$ where $d_K = \mathrm{disc}(K)$.

I'm guessing this will somehow use the fact that the $d_K$ in an integer but I'm not sure how this being an Galois extension is used.

Comment: @reuns: I believe it is much simpler than conductor-discriminant, all you have to do is to write down the formula for $ \text{disc}(K) $.

Comment: @hellHound right I feel dumb. So it works in any Galois extension $K/F$ : if $b_1,\ldots,b_r$ is a $F$-basis of $K$, let $B_{ij} = \sigma_j(b_i)$, then $(B B^\top)_{il} = Tr_{K/F}(b_i b_l)$, so $\det(B)^2 = \det(B B^\top) \in F$ and $\sqrt{\det(B B^\top)} \in K$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ [K:\mathbb{Q}] = r $ and $ \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q} )= \{ \sigma_1, \cdots, \sigma_r \} $. If $ \alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_r $ is a $ \mathbb{Z} $-basis for the ring of integers $ O_K $ of $ K $, then one definition of the discriminant is $ d_K = [\det (\sigma_i(\alpha_j))_{i,j}]^2 $. As $ K/ \mathbb{Q} $ is Galois, the entries $ \sigma_i(\alpha_j) $ of the matrix are in $ K $. So just expanding this determinant out shows you that $ K $ contains a square root of $ d_K $.